# SQL parser in C

Tags: sql, c, parsing

I want to parse and store the columns and values of a SQL DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) statement in C. Need the URL of the open source code or a library with which I can link my C program. The platform is SUSE Linux. Have tried to make and use libSQL unsuccessfully. A detailed answer is appreciated. Thanks.

*Additional Notes:* Please suggest a library/code that I can link with my C program. In my program I want to use the functions of this library to parse and use the tokens for further processing.

Answer (score 11):

You can have a look at the source code for SQLite. It uses a parser called Lemon.

Links:

> [SQLite architecture](http://www.sqlite.org/arch.html)
>
> [Lemon parser](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html)

You can also look at the source code for postgresql-plpython3. Looks like it has a pure C based SQL parser.

Link:

> [postgresql-plpython3 @ github](http://github.com/jwp/postgresql-plpython3/tree/1e8d471f071ec0d4fceb1041d2ede113a70e002f/src/backend/parser)

Comment: Lemon parser! Didn't know about this. Can't wait to use it in my own project.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to start from the real parser of a real DBMS. There are several in free software. For instance, the parser of [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) is in the directory `src/backend/parser` of the distribution and is written in C and Yacc.

Answer (score 1):

See the Chapter "**Parsing SQL**" in  "Lex & Yacc"(O'Reilly) in google books http://books.google.fr/books?id=YrzpxNYegEkC&lpg=PT1&dq=bison%20flex%20sql%20grammar&client=firefox-a&hl=en&pg=PA109

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) ? It certainly does have the code to parse SQL, so maybe you could avoid reimplementing it..

Answer (score 1):

[ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) can [target C](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3+Code+Generation+-+C), among other languages, and its [catalog of premade grammars](http://antlr.org/grammar/list) has a bunch of SQL dialects - notably MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: The link is broken!

Comment: Things have changed drastically since this was written. ANTLR no longer supports C, for one thing, only C++. But there's a bespoke SQL parser written in C now, as well: https://github.com/xgfn/sqlparser

Answer (score 1):

### [µSQL for C++](http://www.cybergarage.org/oss/cloud/%C2%B5sql-for-c/)

> What is µSQL ?
>
> µSQL is a SQL parser engine for C++ to develop SQL based applications
>   easily, and it supports other SQL like domain specific languages such
>   as UnQL and GQL too. Because µSQL is written only in old standard C++
>   library such as STL with ANTLR, then you can use it with many C++
>   compilers and platforms.

[Repo on Github](https://github.com/cybergarage/uSQL4CC)

Answer (score 1):

The standalone [SQL parser](https://github.com/hyrise/sql-parser) of the Hyrise database system is open source and, even though it is written in C++, it can be accessed from C and is easy to understand and modify. It utilizes bison and flex.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is there any mature C sql parser can do that easily.

Here is a Java version SQL library can do what you need exactly, it can be used to [Retrieve/Refactor table & column name](http://www.sqlparser.com/retrieve-refactor-table-column-name.php) from a complex SQL query easily.

Comment: You may have mentioned that this is a commercial product.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered writing your own using lex and yacc? (the hacker - hardcore approach)

Not trivial .. but [this site](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~SqlParser~VFP) might help you get started